# Django - Users inconsistently registered to Admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-2.1

This is the default User model, nothing custom, no modifications to Auth in any way. I am using Django 2.1.

**Depot/Admin.py**

```
import depot.models as models
from django.contrib import admin
from django.db.models.base import ModelBase
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

admin.site.site_header = "DSG IT Database"
for model_name in dir(models):
    model = getattr(models, model_name)
    if isinstance(model, ModelBase):
        if model in admin.site._registry: 
            admin.site.unregister(model)
        else:
            admin.site.register(model)
```

**Stores/Admin.py**

```
import stores.models as models
from django.contrib import admin
from django.db.models.base import ModelBase
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

admin.site.site_header = "DSG IT Database"
for model_name in dir(models):
    model = getattr(models, model_name)
    if isinstance(model, ModelBase):
        if model in admin.site._registry: 
            admin.site.unregister(model)
        else:
            admin.site.register(model)
```

I do understand these are *sort of* redundant, but that isn't the problem because this was an issue when this was a single application project as well.

[image]

What is happening is that `Users` is just completely missing from the admin site. I can register it again with `admin.site.register(User)`, but then later down the road (seemingly randomly) I'll get an error that `User` is already registered. Then I `unregister` the model, and it'll work for a while then at some point Users will just disappear again and the only way to make it work again is by registering it again.

I can't find where I need to be to debug this. I'm assuming somewhere the model is being registered but only under certain conditions I'm unsure of. Has anyone had an issue similar to this?

Please feel free to ask me to include any information you feel will help diagnose!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `stores.models` imports `User` it will be listed in `dir(models)` and since `ModelBase` is the Django metaclass for all Django models:

```
isinstance(User, ModelBase)   # Is True
```

So, the `User` model is not there because you are unregistering it.

You could use:

```
from django.apps import apps

stores_app_config = apps.get_app_config('stores')

for model in stores_app_config.get_models():
    # process models from stores app here.
```

Proposed reading: [Python metaclasses.](https://realpython.com/python-metaclasses/)

Comment: I'll definitely look into this, but as I said this was an identical issue when it was a single application project too. For clarity, when I would register `User` it is done so above `admin.site.site_header`. IF I'm understanding you correctly. You may also be saying that my loop is causing it to intermittently unregister? EDIT: I think I understand you now, let me try it out.

Comment: Yes, if the `User` model is imported by `stores.model` it will definitely unregistered in your loop, since this `isinstance(User, ModelBase)` is true. Try using `get_models` function to implement your loop.

Comment: Got it, that makes perfect sense, I wasn't thinking about that. Are you certain on the locations of `get_app` and `get_models`? Can't find them in `django.db.models`.

Comment: `from django.apps.app import get_app, get_models` is the location for 1.7+. Thanks for your help, I'll accept this after a day or 2 if the issue doesn't present itself!

Comment: Ok, glad to help.

Comment: Do you know where these are in Django 2.0+? All everyone is saying is that its been deprecated but I can't find anywhere where this was replaced? Is it just gone then, and if so I'll have to specify my version in the question to find a solution compatible.

Comment: in Django 2 is a method of `AppConfig`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187202/discussion-between-raydel-miranda-and-codespent).